# Translation of "template entry"

Tags: english-to-german, technical-terminology

I'm translating some web UI text from English to German that appears in a drop down list.  There are two options in the list in English:

- Manual entry
- Template entry

This value controls which input form a user is shown when creating a new agenda "entry".  For "Manual entry" the user types all the values into text boxes.  For "Template entry" some values are already pre-selected based on a template set up in another part of the system.

For "Manual entry" Manueller Eintrag seems to be a good translation, but I have struggled to find a good translation for "Template entry".  There are quite a few nouns for "template" in German, but no adjective that I could find.

What would be a good translation for "Template entry" in the given context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective (a participle in fact) you look for is **vorgegeben**.

> Vorgegebene Werte verwenden

But German speakers like nouns more than verbs and so

> Vorgabewerte verwenden
>
> Verwendung von Vorgabewerten
>
> Eingabe mit Vorgabewerten

sound more German.

---

A thing about **Eintrag**. That one addresses the item, the action is **Eintragen** or **Eingeben**. **Eingabe** conveys both.

So a menu could list

> 1. Manuelle Eingabe
> 2. Eingabe mit Vorgabewerten

Comment: Da es die akzeptierte Antwort ist: mir fehlt hier noch die ***Maske***, bzw, ***Eingabemaske*** für das *Eingabefeld*.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't have an corresponding adjective, you can use the noun itself and make a composite noun. This is a wonderful property of the German language.

I'd propose:

> Schabloneneintrag
>
> Mustereintrag
> Vorlageneintrag

Comment: Vielleicht "Vorlageneintrag", mit n zwischen e und e?

Comment: Das ist sicher besser so, @userunknown. Ich editiere es nach deinem Vorschlag

Answer (score -1):

I propose to have a less verbose translation. In a more technical document the English *Combo-Box* is typically used (*Auswahlfeld*, if it has to be German), or the admittedly long but precise term *Auswahl eines von mehreren vorgegebenen Werten*. I assume, the context is to provide some prefabricated answers and a text entry field, if none of these matches.